# How proceed only first frame for gifs when resizing ActiveStorage blob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage, minimagick

I'm making migration from paperclip to activestorage and have a lot of gif files.

In paperclip I used animated:false option, with thumbnails.

How to resize only first frame for activestorage variant?

I found that gem used for this mini_magick, and it have option collapsed, but can't join this together.

if it important, I'm using google_cloude_storage as images storage.

Answer (score 1):

Variant option is not working? It should return still frame (first frame) from gif. You will need gem for image variant processing: `gem "image_processing"`.

More details:
https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html

Preview first frame with resize option:

> = image_tag image.variant(resize: "170x170").processed

Return full animated gif:

> = image_tag image

Comment: The problem is that it generate small gif, with broken frames. Not only first frame. I found option for mogrify app(for resizing), but can't find how to pass frame number